# Passing a yaml array containing package data to puppet through Hiera

Tags: automation, yaml, puppet, hiera

puppet version: 4.9.4
hiera version: 3.3.1

What i am trying to do is have httpd reload when a new version of package-x/y is installed, and it doesn't seem like the array from Hiera is being passed correctly.

for my httpd.pp file, I have:

```
class service::common::httpd (
  $service_state = undef, # undef = unmanaged
  $service_run_at_boot = undef,
  $packages = undef
  ) {
    service { 'httpd':
      ensure     => $service_state,
      enable     => $service_run_at_boot,
      subscribe  => $packages,
      restart    => "/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful"
    }
  }
```

and in the yaml file for hiera, I have:

```
service::common::httpd::packages: [Package['package-x'],Package['package-y']]
```

running puppet with this gives the error

```
Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Lookup of key 'allow_virtual_packages' failed: Unable to parse (/root/repos/puppet-config/data/nodes/<location of yaml file>): did not find expected ',' or ']' while parsing a flow sequence
```

also saying that its `missing a comma between flow collection entries`. I've tried many different combinations of spaces and commas as well..

I have also tried including the packages inside the class with an include statement.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Relevant YAML documentation can be found at https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2802662 as well as other deocumentation for YAML syntax.

Comment: This is not merely a YAML documentation issue as Puppet requires the references in the YAML file to be formatted in a quite unintuitive way, per my answer below. Actually, it is a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [yamllint](https://github.com/adrienverge/yamllint) utility is quite useful for analysing Puppet Hiera YAML files. When I tried it on your file I got:

```
▶ yamllint spec/fixtures/hiera/data/common.yaml 
spec/fixtures/hiera/data/common.yaml
  2:25      error    syntax error: expected ',' or ']', but got '['
  2:39      error    too few spaces after comma  (commas)
```

The syntax error there reveals that the file is simply invalid YAML.

But how to fix it?

Confusingly, a line in a Puppet manifest like:

```
  subscribe => [Package['package-x'], Package['package-y']]
```

When compiled into a JSON Puppet catalog becomes:

```
  "subscribe": ["Package[package-x]", "Package[package-y]"]
```

And you can place the same JSON string in the YAML file to make valid YAML like this:

```
service::common::httpd::packages: ["Package[package-x]", "Package[package-y]"]
```

You can also use single quotes in the YAML i.e.

```
service::common::httpd::packages: ['Package[package-x]', 'Package[package-y]']
```

More info on how to compile the Puppet catalog in my blog post [here](https://alexharv074.github.io/2016/03/16/dumping-the-catalog-in-rspec-puppet.html).

Answer (score 0):

quotes.

hiera doesn't know what `Package` is. just quote it, since its a string.

> service::common::httpd::packages: [ "Package['package-x']",
>   "Package['package-y']" ]

works perfectly.

---

or you can just change `[ "Package['package-x']", "Package['package-y']" ]` to `[ 'package-x', 'package-y' ]`

works flawlessly. see below.

**host01.yaml**

```
beats::packetbeat::packages: [ acl, htop ]
```

**packetbeat.pp**

```
class beats::packetbeat (
    $packages = undef
) {
    package {
        "packetbeat":
            ensure    => "$version",
            subscribe => Package[$packages],
        ;
    } 
}
```

> Notice: /Stage[main]/Beats::Packetbeat/Package[acl]/ensure:
>   current_value 'absent', should be '2.2.51-14.el7' (noop)
>
> Notice: /Stage[main]/Beats::Packetbeat/Package[packetbeat]: Would have
>   triggered 'refresh' from 1 event
>
> Notice: /Stage[main]/Beats::Packetbeat/Service[packetbeat]: Would have
>   triggered 'refresh' from 2 events
>
> Notice: Class[Beats::Packetbeat]: Would have triggered 'refresh' from
>   3 events

Comment: This is incorrect. It would lead to a compilation error, `Could not find resource 'Package['package-x']' in parameter 'require'`. Puppet will treat the quotes around package-x as part of the title. I already posted a correct (and tested) answer below.

Comment: @AlexHarvey it works. i would never post an answer here without testing. if you want to check i can screenshot the result and upload somewhere.

Comment: Ok I tested using your code and leads to a compilation error. What puppet version?

Comment: I have tested the code for latest Puppet 6, 5, and 4 and in all versions a compilation error is seen using the code you suggested. Gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/alexharv074/47b2238ec9183491dceaae1d31837820). Note that your update to the post shows you testing something else altogether.